# Указать не точный путь обращения в php

Tags: php

Есть двухязычный сайт en/ru. Для русской версии используются файлы типа: ru.index.html, ru.contact.html, а для иностранного соответственно:  en.index.html, en.contact.html.

Сейчас каждая страница прописывается отдельно таким вот кодом

```
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cms/login.php");

$rurl = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if ($rurl=="/ru.index.html" || $rurl=="/ru.catalog.html")
        {$menu_item="
            <li class = 'menu-item'><a href = '/ru.catalog.html' class = 'menu-item__link'> Ссылка </a></li>
            <li class = 'menu-item'><a href = '/' class = 'menu-item__link'> Ссылка 2 </a></li>
            ";}
?>
```

И тут возник вопрос: А как можно указать не точный путь страницы или файла сайта, чтобы не перечислять каждый раз созданную новую страницу? что-то вроде такого  if ($rurl=="/ru.*.html"), если страница начинается с ru, то выполнить код.

Comment: конкретно для этой задачи лучше проверять содержимое атрибута lang тега html на странице

Comment: Возможно это было бы и практичней, и правильней, но я вообще не владею познаниями в программировании))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предположем что в переменной $rurl у Вас строка, содержащая имя страницы, тогда Вам нужно что то вроде этого.

```
if ( substr($rurl, 0, 2) === 'ru') {
    ваш код вы этом случае...
    введите сюда код
}
```

или же вот так, если в начале есть бэк-слэш:

```
if ( substr($rurl, 0, 3) === '/ru') {
    ваш код вы этом случае...
    введите сюда код
}
```

или же вообще, проверять вхождение подстроки '/ru' в строку, и не важно в начале, середине или конце. Может быть полезно если у Вас вложенность страниц и не понятно до конца где именно будет встречаться '/ru'.

```
if (str_contains($rurl, '/ru')) {
    ваш код вы этом случае...
    введите сюда код
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, в моём случае сработал предложенный вами код с бэк-слешем "/".

При использовании первого варианта (без слеша) ничего не произошло, 
А последний сделал страницу сайта полностью белой